# KendoUI Grid dataSource to json

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui

I have an error on getting the data from the Grid as a json object

```
$('#AttachmentsGrid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.view().toJSON()
```

> TypeError: $("#AttachmentsGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.view().toJSON is not a function

Comment: Your syntax looks fine.  Can you add more code?

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
JSON.stringify($('#AttachmentsGrid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.view())
```